# Node Express force all static routes to point to root path

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a node.js application that I am trying to genericize so that no matter the URL on the back end it always uses the root path to serve static files.

So currently my app sits at https://myapp.heroku.com

I have some js, css, images and a few other static files.

What I want is when the url looks like https://myapp.heroku.com/brand/somebrand that the files that are served are served form the root as well including any internal references inside said files.

I have ensured that all paths begin with a '/' and have also tried the following in every combination possible.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public', options));    
app.use('*', express.static(__dirname + '/public', options));    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

am I on the right track?

This app is actually being loaded by another system which may actually be the problem, unfortunately I cannot debug on that system so I need to rule this out first.