# Node.js + Express.js: How to use the root (/) for serving static files?

Tags: node.js, express

how do we serve a static file located in the root of the directory (/) and not in a folder of it?
I am using Node.js with Express.js, I have tried the following JavaScript code in my `index.js` file which is located in `/` (the root of the directory).

**Attempt 1**

```js
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
})
```

**Attempt 2**

```js
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/'));
})
```

*Same output as Attempt 1*

**Attempt 3**

```
app.use(express.static('/'));
```

- Didn't work, showed an error: "Cannot GET /".

**Attempt 4**

```
app.use(express.static(''));
```

- Didn't work, showed an error: "Path cannot be empty".

Please assist, I have refered to many other possible questions similar to this, and [one of the questions didn't have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081749/node-express-force-all-static-routes-to-point-to-root-path), so I am re-asking.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction? Currently we have not enough information.

Comment: The first attempt looks right. Which error do you see?

Comment: I didn't see any error, it worked BUT when I add static code in that index.html file (such as "<script src="/example.js>"), it doesn't add the script and in the browser console it shows an error: "The resource from “/test.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There isnt any difference if you use / and no / in the script

for express use

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/'));

Answer (score 1):

The argument you pass to `express.static` needs to be the path to the directory where the file is.

It shouldn't be `/` which is the root of the *entire file system* (you might intend it to be the URL path `/` and not the file system path `/` but that isn't what it means).

The special variables [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname) will give you the directory the JS file you are currently running is in. You probably want that (assuming a directory structure like this):

```
.../
   |-server.js
   |-index.html
```

So

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

---

Note that it is generally better to separate out your server-side code and the files you sent to the client. It makes it much easier to maintain the project in the long run and **prevents your server side code (which might contain secrets) being exposed over HTTP** by the `static` module.

Answer (score -2):

try this it might be helpful

app.use(express.static('/'));

you do not need the "/" before "js" because it is already included above:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I have tried this in attempt three, shows an error and does not work.